# Didn't find class "my.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, gradle

Im using 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0' and get error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.mtagrecovery/my.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

how to solve this problem?

Comment: This has too little context: What is the code that throws the error?

Comment: Try using this on your application class `MultiDex.install(this)`. Check more from here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-gradle